# How to avoid fade animation in UICollectionView when update constraints

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

When update constraints for UICollectionView (scale down or upscale),
items are (scale down or upscale) with fade animation.
How to avoid this?

```
// activating constraints:
containerLeft = containerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor)
containerRight = containerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor)
containerTop =  containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
containerBottom = containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)

containerLeft.isActive = true
containerRight.isActive = true
containerTop.isActive = true
containerBottom.isActive = true
```

Function for changing constraints:

```
func setinsetsForContainer(left: CGFloat, right: CGFloat, top:CGFloat, bottom:CGFloat?){
        containerLeft.constant = left
        containerRight.constant = -right
        containerTop.constant = top
        containerBottom.constant = -bottom!
}
```

animatedupdateConstraints:

```
setinsetsForContainer(left: 20, right: 20, top:100, bottom:100)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
 self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just override this methods In ***UICollectionViewFlowLayout***

```
// disable fade animation in cells
    override func initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItem(at itemIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attribute = super.initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItem(at: itemIndexPath)
        attribute?.alpha = 1
        return attribute
    }

    override func finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItem(at itemIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attribute = super.finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItem(at: itemIndexPath)
        attribute?.alpha = 1
        return attribute
    }

//    disable fade animation in header/footer
    override func initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingSupplementaryElement(ofKind elementKind: String, at elementIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attribute = super.initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingSupplementaryElement(ofKind: elementKind, at: elementIndexPath)
        attribute?.alpha = 1
        return attribute
    }

    override func finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingSupplementaryElement(ofKind elementKind: String, at elementIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attribute = super.finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingSupplementaryElement(ofKind: elementKind, at: elementIndexPath)
        attribute?.alpha = 1
        return attribute
    }
```

Comment: Woah works perfectly, thanks! You can also animate it with `self.flowLayout.invalidateLayout()`